# ORA-24237: object id argument passed to DBMS_UTILITY.INVALIDATE is not legal

Tags: oracle

I have had invalid public synonyms in my database. Some of them references to ordinary schema objects and others to sys schema objects.

I compiled all these public synonyms by the following command:

```
alter public synonym mysynonym_name compile;
```

My supervisor suddenly told me that I should not have compiled SYS schema synonyms. I tried to invalidate them by the following way:

```
exec dbms_utility.invalidate(444849);
```

Where 444849 is the synonym object ID. But got the following error:

```
ORA-24237: object id argument passed to DBMS_UTILITY.INVALIDATE is not legal
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 1053
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Why?

Can compilation of these synonyms cause some problem?

Thank you a lot, I am waiting for your recommendations and answers. Please share your knowledge with us.

Comment: Note: I have granted the following privileges to SYS schema:
CREATE ANY DIMENSION,
CREATE ANY EVALUATION CONTEXT
CREATE ANY INDEX
CREATE ANY INDEXTYPE
CREATE ANY LIBRARY
CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE ANY OPERATOR
CREATE ANY PROCEDURE
CREATE ANY RULE
CREATE ANY RULE SET
CREATE ANY SYNONYM
CREATE ANY TRIGGER
CREATE ANY TYPE
CREATE ANY VIEW

but did not help...

Comment: Note2: I found that DBMS_UTILITY.INVALIDATE also invalidates any objects that (directly or indirectly) depend on the object being invalidated :((((((( I don't want it :S

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the create privileges on the object being invalidated. But generally it is a very bad idea to invalidate objects in the sys schema. This will also invalidate all objects that reference them, so you might end up with lots of invalidated objects.

Comment: I am sys user, and synonym is mine. Is there any possibility that I don't have create permission on it. As I said I have granted CREATE ANY SYNONYM to SYS schema...

Comment: its not the right on the synonym its the right on the underlying object